# How to make Instantiated Game Objects script act separately for every object. Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script for that Instantiates 2 game object but when something happens to one of them it also happens to the another one even when the conditions are not met for it. **How can I make the script act separately for every Game Object?**

GO script:

```
private Transform target;
public float speed = 2f;
private Animator anim;

public float H2Damage = 5f;

private healthBar Hp;
void Start()
{
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("enemy").GetComponent<Transform>();
 
    anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();

    Hp = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("enemy").GetComponentInChildren<healthBar>();

}
void Update()
{
    target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("enemy").GetComponent<Transform>();
    if (Hp.Died == true)
    {
        Hp.Died = false;
        anim.SetBool("Hero2Attack", false);
        anim.SetBool("Hero2Move", true);
    }
    if (!target || this.anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Hero2ATTACK"))
        return;
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    anim.SetBool("Hero2Move", true);
}
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("enemy"))
    {
        anim.SetBool("Hero2Attack", true);
        healthBar hp = col.transform.GetComponent<healthBar>();
        hp.GiveDamage(H2Damage);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I would love to help, but could you please show us the code that instantiates them?

Comment: It's simple Instantiate attached to a button: private void TaskOnClick() 
{
Instantiate(Hero2Child,Pos1, Quaternion.identity);
Instantiate(Hero2Child,Pos2, Quaternion.identity);
} //this is attached to a button

Comment: @Walter should I use foreach. If yes how? I am noob in c# 

Answer (score 0):

I believe they act the same way because they are getting the same `GetComponentWithTag()`, so they will **Get the same objects**. You also instantiate the animator, which is the exact same one, so they will do the same things. --> If it was as simple as changing the position by 1 meter per second, they would have different behavior (ie. be at different positions) But.... If you instantiate it, the current position is also instantiated, so you are going to have to get the current postion and set it to what you want, so both of these moving boxes aren't at the exact same position. You will have to do something similar here, you are going to want to either (create different scripts for the objects, or set the script values to different things)

TL;DR: You are copying the exact same script with the exact same components, so they will act similarly.

Fix: The only way to fix this is by setting their values after you instantiate them using `GetComponent<>()`or changing the script you assign them. (or any components for that matter)

---

Let me know if you have any problems or questions in the comments! :)